# Excerpts in search results breaks MathJax fragments

Tags: bug, mathjax, search

For example:

https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional+expectation+user%3Auser130272

[image]

The problem, of course, is that the excerpt extraction code apparently is not aware of MathJax boundaries. In the example above, it spits the following:

```
            <div class="excerpt">
                $ be the maximum of the three values, let $Y_2$ be their product, 
             ....
            </div>
```

Update: Well, this seems to have been already addressed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/formatting-in-the-search-results-page-breaks-when-the-query-contains-certain-ter?rq=1) (I did a search before asking, but didn't find  it - the "Related" sidebar is clever indeed). Feel free to close this as dup if appropiate.

Update 2: The linked post seems to consider that this issue does not deserve to be fixed. Perhaps that should be reconsidered? I copy my comment:

> "we can't reasonably format the bodies because the snippets are
>   outside of our control". I'm not sure of that. Every CMS or blog 
>   has the intelligence to strip out some unwanted content (for example,
>   some HTML or BBCode) in search result pages with excerpts. That an
>   unmatched $ spoils the text is a bug. If it's too difficult to match
>   dollar signs, could't at least escape them, so that the MathJax
>   formatter is not involved and the latex code is shown instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting in the Search Results page breaks when the query contains certain terms](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/formatting-in-the-search-results-page-breaks-when-the-query-contains-certain-ter)