# Custom TeX command doesn't render in search results

Tags: bug, mathjax, search, newcommand

In my answer to [Collecting Stickers! Evaluate occurrence of duplicates?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787710) I defined a custom TeX command `\stir`, which is rendered correctly on the page itself. When that answer comes up in search results, though, the raw command appears in red:

[image]

Comment: It seems to only show a part of that answer, and not the part where the command is defined.

Comment: Related posts (but probably not duplicates): (1) [Formatting in the Search Results page breaks when the query contains certain terms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3067); (2) [Excerpts in search results breaks MathJax fragments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13835); (3) [MathJax bugged on front page (FireFox)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20055); (4) [Problem with printing of cases statement on overview](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22641).